# How can I verify if time is set correctly on server in my bash script?

Tags: bash, date, clock-synchronization

I'm working on ultimate backup script for very important server. My script already:

- creates a backup
- verifies copied file(-s)
- verifies gz archive
- compares MD5 on local and remote after sending file to remote server via scp
- removes monthly backups older than 365, weekly backups older than 31 days, daily backups older than 7 days, hourly backups older than 24 hours
- checks for available disk space on local and remote machine
- sends email report if some errors ocurred
- sends email report for weekly backups

In addition to all this, I miss one important thing - clock verification on local and remote because it affects the naming and removal of copies.

How can I make sure if date and time are set correctly in bash in a simple and reliable way?

If possible - it would be nice if that method could work on Windows server with cygwin.

I'm not asking for complete solution, just advice for taking correct and not complex approach.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/1077601/how-to-check-whether-the-system-time-is-synchronised-to-ntp-server-without-knowi

Comment: @stark thats pretty complicated, I need some kind of bash one-two liner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command in Linux:

```
date +%s
```

and in Windows (PowerShell)

```
Get-Date -UFormat %s
```

to get [epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Those numbers can be easy compared.

P.S. For Windows you may need to strip the number to integer like this:

```
$t3 = (Get-Date -UFormat %s).split(',')[0]
echo $t3
```

**N.B.** Here comma `,` is my decimal number delimiter. Depend of your language you may need to change it.

This command will give you Epoch time from external source (to compare with your machines)

```
curl -s "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Rome" |jq '.unixtime'
```

Feel free to change your timezone

Comment: This is good to compare between two machines, but I need something that checks some reference ntp server.

Comment: @Kamil In such case implement to ALL machines ntp clients

Comment: I have ntp clients on all machines, but I need to be sure that it is working before I start deleting backups older than x days.

Comment: @Kamil, will update the answer to give you time from World source

Comment: Nice, pretty portable (available on cygwin, debian and I don't know what else) but it looks like I would have to to install curl on all servers. I think it is worth.